# Can't start gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am just starting with ROS. On a new Ubuntu 12.04 installation, i issued apt-get ros-fuerte-* and installed everything (except openni-dev that needs SSE3 and i have only SSE2).

Now i can't start gazebo!!

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch 
... logging to /home/amh/.ros/log/348d8d28-2b9c-11e2-85c7-00166f6382d6/roslaunch-amh-Latitude-D610-17941.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://amh-Latitude-D610:57229/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo/gui)

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [17957]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 348d8d28-2b9c-11e2-85c7-00166f6382d6
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [17970]
started core service [/rosout]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [17984]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [17991]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Msg Waiting for master[ INFO] [1352596072.851921503]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
[ INFO] [1352596074.145719550]: joint trajectory plugin missing <updateRate>, defaults to 0.0 (as fast as possible)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 17984, exit code 132, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/amh/.ros/log/348d8d28-2b9c-11e2-85c7-00166f6382d6/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/amh/.ros/log/348d8d28-2b9c-11e2-85c7-00166f6382d6/gazebo-2*.log
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: line 2: 17994 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) `rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/bin/gzclient -g `rospack find gazebo`/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 17991, exit code 132, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/amh/.ros/log/348d8d28-2b9c-11e2-85c7-00166f6382d6/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/amh/.ros/log/348d8d28-2b9c-11e2-85c7-00166f6382d6/gazebo_gui-3*.log
```

BTW, /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt shows 1.6.16. I am confusing this with 1.0.2 (written in above log) and 1.2 on http://gazebosim.org !!

Please help me getting started with ROS.

Thanks

**Update** I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The output of lspci |grep VGA

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

In the details panel of system settings

```
Graphics: Intel® 915GM x86/MMX/SSE2
Experience: Standard
```

The cpu flags: `fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss tm pbe nx up bts est tm2`

**Update 2**
using "roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world_no_x.launch"

```
... logging to /home/amh/.ros/log/ea152620-2cf9-11e2-96c6-00166f6382d6/roslaunch-amh-Latitude-D610-30993.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://localhost:44406/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [31009]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to ea152620-2cf9-11e2-96c6-00166f6382d6
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [31022]
started core service [/rosout]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [31036]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[1;[ INFO] [1352746273.994021826]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
32mMsg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
[ INFO] [1352746275.484051598]: joint trajectory plugin missing <updateRate>, defaults to 0.0 (as fast as possible)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 31036, exit code 132, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo -r /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/amh/.ros/log/ea152620-2cf9-11e2-96c6-00166f6382d6/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/amh/.ros/log/ea152620-2cf9-11e2-96c6-00166f6382d6/gazebo-2*.log
```

Should roscore be already running before gazebo ? Trying it gives me at the end:

```
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

**Update 3**

```
rosmake gazebo_worlds
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['gazebo_worlds']                          
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/amh/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121113-090955
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['gazebo_worlds'] to:
['gazebo_worlds']              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> xacro [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< xacro ROS_NOBUILD in package xacro                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> ivcon [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ivcon ROS_NOBUILD in package ivcon                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> ogre [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ogre ROS_NOBUILD in package ogre                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> trajectory_msgs [ make ]                              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< trajectory_msgs  No Makefile in package trajectory_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> gazebo_msgs [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< gazebo_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package gazebo_msgs        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> colladadom [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< colladadom ROS_NOBUILD in package colladadom          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdf_interface [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdf_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_interface  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdf_parser [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdf_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_parser        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> collada_parser [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< collada_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_parser  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_srvs  No Makefile in package std_srvs             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs  No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> protobuf [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< protobuf ROS_NOBUILD in package protobuf              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> gazebo [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< gazebo ROS_NOBUILD in package gazebo                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> gazebo_tools [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< gazebo_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package gazebo_tools      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nav_msgs  No Makefile in package nav_msgs             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]                              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs  No Makefile in package diagnostic_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> diagnostic_updater [ make ]                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< diagnostic_updater ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_updater
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> self_test [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< self_test ROS_NOBUILD in package self_test            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> driver_base [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< driver_base ROS_NOBUILD in package driver_base        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl  No Makefile in package pcl                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> gazebo_plugins [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< gazebo_plugins ROS_NOBUILD in package gazebo_plugins  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> gazebo_worlds [ make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< gazebo_worlds ROS_NOBUILD in package gazebo_worlds    
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                           
[ rosmake ] Built 50 packages with 0 failures.                                 
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                        
[ rosmake ] /home/amh/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121113-090955          
amh@amh-Latitude-D610:~/fuerte_workspace$ roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world_no_x.launch
... logging to /home/amh/.ros/log/3d3efb0c-2d61-11e2-aba2-00166f6382d6/roslaunch-amh-Latitude-D610-32411.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://localhost:37385/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [32427]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 3d3efb0c-2d61-11e2-aba2-00166f6382d6
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [32440]
started core service [/rosout]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [32454]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
[ INFO] [1352790652.113045154]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
[ INFO] [1352790653.894700277]: joint trajectory plugin missing <updateRate>, defaults to 0.0 (as fast as possible)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 32454, exit code 132, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo -r /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/amh/.ros/log/3d3efb0c-2d61-11e2-aba2-00166f6382d6/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/amh/.ros/log/3d3efb0c-2d61-11e2-aba2-00166f6382d6/gazebo-2*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47959/can%27t-start-gazebo/) by [amh](https://answers.ros.org/users/3565/amh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-11**:
1.6.16 is the version of the simulator_gazebo (ROS) package.. it uses Gazebo 1.0.2 which is a standalone piece of code.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-11**:
Can you edit your question and include some information? What operating system are you using? (e.g. Ubuntu Precise, Debian Squeeze, etc.). What is the result of `lspci |grep VGA` (what graphics card are you using)?

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-12**:
Could you try `roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world_no_x.launch`

**Comment by [amh](https://answers.ros.org/users/3565/amh/) on 2012-11-12**:
still the same error (Update 2)

**Comment by [amh](https://answers.ros.org/users/3565/amh/) on 2012-11-12**:
@Amal Please check my Update 3

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-13**:
@amh roslaunch starts a roscore if there isn't already one running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that it truly may be the gazebo server that is segfaulting...

I'd suggest running `roslaunch gazebo_worlds debug.launch` and reporting the issue  on [Gazebo Trac](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/new)

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0